# Change label on an mxgraph cell/vertex

Tags: javascript, mxgraph, jgraph

I've created an interface, including mxgraph (javascript), that allows a user to click on a cell and edit the cell's label in a regular form text input that's separate from the graph.  I'd like to change the cell's label after the user saves the form (ajax submit) without having to reload the graph.

I really don't need to do anything fancy with a cell/vertext label, but I do need to be able to change it's text.  I don't need HTML labels if that's avoidable.  And, I haven't found something like a "setLabel" method in the API.

Sounds like a simply thing.  What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Set the value on the [cell via the model](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/model/mxGraphModel-js.html#mxGraphModel.setValue):

```
graph.model.setValue(cell, value);
```